# $\Phi$ a quadratic form, then $\sqrt{\Phi (x+y)} = \sqrt{\Phi (x)} + \sqrt{\Phi (y)}$ if $x= \lambda y for x,y, \lambda \in \mathbb{K}$

Tags: quadratic-forms

I'm trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

$\Phi$ a positive quadratic form on $\mathbb{K}^n$, then $\sqrt{\Phi (x+y)} = \sqrt{\Phi (x)} + \sqrt{\Phi (y)}$ if $x= \lambda y$ for $x,y, \lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ and $\lambda \neq 0$

Since $\Phi$ is a quadratic form, it can be rewritten as:

$\Phi(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

$\Phi (y) = dy^2+ey + f$

$\Phi(x+y)  = g(x+y)^2 + h(x+y) + j$

Where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j$ are constants.

Am I allowed to rewrite the quadratic form $\Phi$ in such a way if I don't know the explicit function?

Comment: What is your definition of a (positive) quadratic form? What does $\Phi(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ mean for $x \in  \Bbb K^n$?

Comment: We say that $\Phi (x)$ is a positive quadratic form if and only if for all $ x \in \mathbb{K}^n$ it holds that $\Phi(x) \ge 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

If $x = \lambda y$ then $\Phi(x+y) = \Phi((\lambda+1)y) = (\lambda+1)^2\Phi(y)$ and $\Phi(x) = \lambda^2\Phi(y)$

Comment: .This helped a lot! So the solution would be:

If $x = \lambda y \Rightarrow \sqrt{\Phi (x+y)} = (\lambda + 1) \sqrt{\Phi (y)}$ And $\sqrt{\Phi (x)} + \sqrt{\Phi (y)} = \lambda \sqrt{\Phi (y)} + \sqrt{\Phi (y)}  = (\lambda + 1)\sqrt{\Phi (y)} $. So the statement is true. But why did it have to be a positive quadratic form?

Comment: Because then we couldn't compute $\sqrt{\Phi(x)}$

Comment: oh, of course. Thanks!